# Can you change the screen direction when transition between pages in Oracle APEX?

Tags: javascript, jquery, oracle-apex

I am using the jquery mobile apex application. I am navigating to different pages based on a dynamic action event, and I am using the following javascript code to navigate between the pages:

```
apex.navigation.redirect("URL");
```

I am using this to go back a page and need the new page to appear from left to right instead of right to left, so it looks better. I know there is a transition attribute: `page-transition="slide" data-direction="reverse"` [source](https://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.2.0/docs/pages/page-transitions.html)

Is there javascript that can accomplish this or is this not possible to control in apex? And can this be implemented with the apex page navigation?

Anything will be helpful, Thanks.

Comment: Do I understand correctly: your issue is not in apex buttons or generated links, since you call `apex.navigation.redirect` yourself in javascript code?

Comment: Yes it is not in apex buttons or generated links. I am using the swipe feature of dynamic action and am redirecting pages with the 'apex.navigation.redirect' The problem is that I am trying to reverse the page transition when I navigate to the other page. Would you know if that is a possibility? Thanks @Tom